# Use wordpress the_ID() inside a custom wordpress table?

Tags: php, database

I have a custom DB and I need to assign the data to the post id it came from...

```
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "customtable";

 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$table_name` (
          `id` int(10) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT, //instead of AUTO_INCREMENT how can I assign post_id?
          `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
          `data` text NOT NULL,
          `date_c` int(10) NOT NULL,
          `date_m` int(11) NOT NULL,
          `flag_hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          `flag_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
```

By assigning the `post_id` to the `id` column, I should be able to get the data like `get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_moon_sortable_content', false);` right?

Comment: no, `get_post_meta` is for the post meta, ie. data that is in wp_postmeta, not your custom table.

Comment: ok, yeah I know its in wp_postmeta but I need a custom table and cant use wp_postmeta, I also need to associate the data in the table with the post id... there has to be a way to associate the id of a post with the data...

Comment: so what's your question? you may want to edit your post, as it looks like your question is the last sentence, which the answer would be no.

Comment: Ok then could you help shed some light on the first sentence? "I have a custom DB and I need to assign the data to the post id it came from..." how do I write `the_ID()` as the datbases id?

Comment: you wouldn't set id to the post_id, since 1. it's auto_increment, and 2. we don't know if this table can contain multiple entries from a post etc. what you would do is 1. create another column for post_id, name it `post_id`. 2. when inserting into this table, make sure to set post_id. and that's it.

Comment: Ok sounds good, ill create a new column.. should it be between `id` and `name`

Comment: column position doesn't matter... you may want to learn more on SQL

Comment: Lol I am new but I am just making sure, nothing wrong with that.. writing the SQL query now.. I hope I get it to work. thanks for giving me some kind of direction I was looking in the wrong places, thats just a waste of time